# iPhone/iPad - Need to offer a free upgrade for Customers who brought an old app

Tags: iphone, store

We have an app on the app store that we need to remove. As such we have a new version to upload as a completely new app with a new app SKU and Id but we want to offer a free upgrade for those who have purchased the original version.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

But if you're willing to give new App for free for everybody who's got an old one why do you create a new application and not just update old one? You can change anything you want about app except SKU# as I understand. Do you have anything tied to old SKU# or you have other reasons to create a new app?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other posters.  Apple does not have a mechanism to do this.

What you can do:
-make a black and white or very washed out icon for the old app
- change the app description to say that this is an old version / no longer supported / deprecated and to search for the new version.
- Make sure the new app title show something like *NEW*, 2.0 or some signifier to draw attention

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard or seen anything about it. Only thing that comes to my mind is to give a promotion code. This of course opens up some other questions:

How to communicate that to your customers?
How to secure that it is not explored by users who have not bought the first app?

Don't have any good answers to that (time limited offer?) but maybe it could lead you to some new ideas.

Good luck!

Comment: Its only possible to give 50 promotional codes/version of app. I think that the way to do it would be to contact the iTunes connect support staff. They're used to doing complex things like moving apps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no real way to do this. Apple intentionally keeps information about the users of your old app private.

Well, there's one way I can think of, but it requires some forethought (and I'm not certain it would be ok by Apple) and it would cost you a bit: When your old app runs it contacts a server of yours with the device's UDID, which you save on the server. Then you show an alert in the old app that tells existing users to contact you via email with their UDID (you could make it easy on the user by putting together the email in-app with the UDID in the subject or body). You then send a gift of the new app (via iTunes) to every user that emailed you that way.

You'd take a 30% hit (Apple's cut) but the rest of the gift price would end up back in your bank account. People who pirated the app would get the offer, too, and there's no way you could tell a pirating user from a valid user. But it would more-or-less work.